# Как в с# делать сериализацию/десериализацию list объекта размером 1gb максимально быстро?

Tags: c#, сериализация

Делаю сейчас десериализацию, как

```
BinaryFormatter bin = new BinaryFormatter();
var test = (List<abc>)bin.Deserialize(stream);
```

но это очень долго. Пожалуйста, подскажите, как сделать быстрее?

Comment: @prog432 вы наивно полагаете, будто в C# есть большая волшебная кнопка с надписью "Turbo", стоит которую нажать, как тут же все начнет выполняться гораздо быстрее? Я вас разочарую - такой кнопки там нет. Ваше слабое звено - это объем данных. Сокращайте его

Comment: @prog432 А долго, это сколько? минута, час, сутки? Давайте посчитаем, средненький диск дает до 100МБайт в секунду. Значит, у меня один гигабайт только на диск будет записываться как минимум 10 секунд. И ускорить это можно только если поставить к примеру SSD.

Comment: долго это больше часа, читаются данные быстро, вопрос их долгой десериализации

Comment: Любопытно, зачем делать сериализацию/десериализацию list объекта размером 1gb?

Comment: @prog432, а может у Вас тривиально не хватает ОЗУ (в т.ч. под все вспомогательные для десериализации структуры данных) и начинается paging?

Comment: есть предложение использовать protobuf или даже сделать свой личный сериализатор.

И, мое личное мнение, перейти на более адекватные языки/алгоритмы или установить хотя бы 8-16 ГБ памяти, если хотите работать с гигабайтными массивами данных.